# How to display the array data in tabular format in smarty in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I've an array titled `$preview_data` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [op] => preview
    [id] => 
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [company_id] => 
    [product_id] => 
    [pack] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 30
            [3] => 40
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 8
        )

    [volume] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 200
            [2] => 300
            [3] => 400
        )

    [units] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 10
        )

    [amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3.00
            [1] => 6.00
            [2] => 9.00
            [3] => 12.00
        )

    [date] => 
    [applicable_states] => 
    [rebate_total_cnt] => 
)
```

Now I've to print the above data in a table format. How should I achieve this. I want the data in table format as below(i.e. the headings of the table are as below):

```
pack   quantity    volume  units   amount
```

The data should be displayed as data from all the respective arrays with same index should be displaye in one line. The next index data on next line and so on. So how to achieve this in smarty with the help of foreach construct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to do what you're asking in PHP? Because you can translate it to Smarty pretty easily.

Comment: @WesleyMurch:I'm anewbie in smarty so I'm not able to do it now. If you could please post an answer for the above code it would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
{foreach from=$preview_data.pack key='index' item='value'}
<tr>
   <td>{$value}</td>
   <td>{$preview_data.quantity[$index]}</td>
   <td>{$preview_data.volume[$index]}</td>
   <td>{$preview_data.units[$index]}</td>
   <td>{$preview_data.amount[$index]}</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
```